# Подскажите, что написать.

Tags: java

Возможно мой вопрос несколько глуп, но все же. Прочитал книгу по java,а с чего начать писать незнаю. Подскажите пожалуйста, что написать для начала...

Comment: я решал задачи которые в сети находил они не плохо набивают руку 

Comment: Попробуй напечатать триугольники с звездочкой с помощью for if

Answer (score 1):

порешай олимпиадные задачки.
напиши xml парсер, поиграйся с сериализацией объектов вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас модно писать под Андроид. Посему рекомендую пройтись по примерам:

- [Hello, World](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)
- [Hello, Testing](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html)
- [Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html)

А затем уже написать что-нибудь простое самостоятельно, например, крестики-нолики или судоку. В результате и в Java освоитесь, и про Андроид узнаете.